# How can I compile JS and JSON together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, gulp

I have a project where the prod machine specs are low so I'm trying something new and trying Gulp to compile everything into one compressed js file.

I have a `config.json` that's being used by `main.js`. What does my `gulpfile.js` has to look like in order to turn those two files into one js file?

Answer (score 0):

You may declare a variable in **JS** to contain the JSON data as per following example

```
var arr = [
       {
          data1: 'mydata01',
          data2: 'mydata02',
       },
       {
          data3: 'mydata03',
          data4: 'mydata04',
       }
     ]
```

But this defeats the spirit and purpose of JSON which is primarily for exchanging of Data between two entities (two webpages, client-server, webpage-database, etc). This technique will make the data hardcoded in the **JS** with lesser flexibility to change the data dynamically.